# Cannot access nested JSON list of dictionaries key via pandas.json_normalize()

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, json-normalize

I'm retrieving a response from spotify API containing a key "artists", the key contains a list of dictionaries for artist details (name, uri, type),
I'm trying to retrieve a list of artists names per record in a pandas column "Artists"
I am using pandas.json_normalize but it doesn't seem to work with this the key "artists".

Here is a code sample top get the top 3 tracks:

```
topTracksResponse = requests.get(top_tracks,headers=headers)
RespJson2 = topTracksResponse.json()
RespJson2['items']
```

```
[{'album': {'album_type': 'SINGLE',
   'artists': [{'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/7zWFKl03Xg50gKryaEH0gu'},
     'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/7zWFKl03Xg50gKryaEH0gu',
     'id': '7zWFKl03Xg50gKryaEH0gu',
     'name': 'Intomymind',
     'type': 'artist',
     'uri': 'spotify:artist:7zWFKl03Xg50gKryaEH0gu'},
    {'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/0QDlkRZ349RXtT5XcwcLRP'},
     'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/0QDlkRZ349RXtT5XcwcLRP',
     'id': '0QDlkRZ349RXtT5XcwcLRP',
     'name': 'DizzyTooSkinny',
     'type': 'artist',
     'uri': 'spotify:artist:0QDlkRZ349RXtT5XcwcLRP'}],
   'available_markets': ['AD',
    'AE',
    'AR',
    'AT',
    'AU',
    'BE',
    'BG',
    'BH',
    'BO',
    'BR',
    'CA',
    'CH',
    'CL',
    'CO',
    'CR',
    'CY',
    'CZ',
    'DE',
    'DK',
    'DO',
    'DZ',
    'EC',
    'EE',
    'EG',
    'ES',
    'FI',
    'FR',
    'GB',
    'GR',
    'GT',
    'HK',
    'HN',
    'HU',
    'ID',
    'IE',
    'IL',
    'IN',
    'IS',
    'IT',
    'JO',
    'JP',
    'KW',
    'LB',
    'LI',
    'LT',
    'LU',
    'LV',
    'MA',
    'MC',
    'MT',
    'MX',
    'MY',
    'NI',
    'NL',
    'NO',
    'NZ',
    'OM',
    'PA',
    'PE',
    'PH',
    'PL',
    'PS',
    'PT',
    'PY',
    'QA',
    'RO',
    'SA',
    'SE',
    'SG',
    'SK',
    'SV',
    'TH',
    'TN',
    'TR',
    'TW',
    'US',
    'UY',
    'VN',
    'ZA'],
   'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/2lmYF8HWF3DYeVR3P6SYf4'},
   'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/2lmYF8HWF3DYeVR3P6SYf4',
   'id': '2lmYF8HWF3DYeVR3P6SYf4',
   'images': [{'height': 640,
     'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b273fbc6dca6a802da6797b0464e',
     'width': 640},
    {'height': 300,
     'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e02fbc6dca6a802da6797b0464e',
     'width': 300},
    {'height': 64,
     'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00004851fbc6dca6a802da6797b0464e',
     'width': 64}],
   'name': 'BrainStorm',
   'release_date': '2021-11-08',
   'release_date_precision': 'day',
   'total_tracks': 1,
   'type': 'album',
   'uri': 'spotify:album:2lmYF8HWF3DYeVR3P6SYf4'},
  'artists': [{'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/7zWFKl03Xg50gKryaEH0gu'},
    'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/7zWFKl03Xg50gKryaEH0gu',
    'id': '7zWFKl03Xg50gKryaEH0gu',
    'name': 'Intomymind',
    'type': 'artist',
    'uri': 'spotify:artist:7zWFKl03Xg50gKryaEH0gu'},
   {'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/0QDlkRZ349RXtT5XcwcLRP'},
    'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/0QDlkRZ349RXtT5XcwcLRP',
    'id': '0QDlkRZ349RXtT5XcwcLRP',
    'name': 'DizzyTooSkinny',
    'type': 'artist',
    'uri': 'spotify:artist:0QDlkRZ349RXtT5XcwcLRP'}],
  'available_markets': ['AD',
   'AE',
   'AR',
   'AT',
   'AU',
   'BE',
   'BG',
   'BH',
   'BO',
   'BR',
   'CA',
   'CH',
   'CL',
   'CO',
   'CR',
   'CY',
   'CZ',
   'DE',
   'DK',
   'DO',
   'DZ',
   'EC',
   'EE',
   'EG',
   'ES',
   'FI',
   'FR',
   'GB',
   'GR',
   'GT',
   'HK',
   'HN',
   'HU',
   'ID',
   'IE',
   'IL',
   'IN',
   'IS',
   'IT',
   'JO',
   'JP',
   'KW',
   'LB',
   'LI',
   'LT',
   'LU',
   'LV',
   'MA',
   'MC',
   'MT',
   'MX',
   'MY',
   'NI',
   'NL',
   'NO',
   'NZ',
   'OM',
   'PA',
   'PE',
   'PH',
   'PL',
   'PS',
   'PT',
   'PY',
   'QA',
   'RO',
   'SA',
   'SE',
   'SG',
   'SK',
   'SV',
   'TH',
   'TN',
   'TR',
   'TW',
   'US',
   'UY',
   'VN',
   'ZA'],
  'disc_number': 1,
  'duration_ms': 150422,
  'explicit': True,
  'external_ids': {'isrc': 'QZK6K2048245'},
  'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/track/6CK4ZX8WhOpkwXf3oO4Uw7'},
  'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/6CK4ZX8WhOpkwXf3oO4Uw7',
  'id': '6CK4ZX8WhOpkwXf3oO4Uw7',
  'is_local': False,
  'name': 'BrainStorm',
  'popularity': 28,
  'preview_url': 'https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/b3a24dfd98cfdd2ef7f083c4b4316ab78c684eab?cid=241941eb6adf401aa17987ff97a7d72e',
  'track_number': 1,
  'type': 'track',
  'uri': 'spotify:track:6CK4ZX8WhOpkwXf3oO4Uw7'},
 {'album': {'album_type': 'ALBUM',
   'artists': [{'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/6CGE1o9Swi1tAEa23wRTah'},
     'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/6CGE1o9Swi1tAEa23wRTah',
     'id': '6CGE1o9Swi1tAEa23wRTah',
     'name': 'Mousv',
     'type': 'artist',
     'uri': 'spotify:artist:6CGE1o9Swi1tAEa23wRTah'}],
   'available_markets': ['AD',
    'AE',
    'AR',
    'AT',
    'AU',
    'BE',
    'BG',
    'BH',
    'BO',
    'BR',
    'CA',
    'CH',
    'CL',
    'CO',
    'CR',
    'CY',
    'CZ',
    'DE',
    'DK',
    'DO',
    'DZ',
    'EC',
    'EE',
    'EG',
    'ES',
    'FI',
    'FR',
    'GB',
    'GR',
    'GT',
    'HK',
    'HN',
    'HU',
    'ID',
    'IE',
    'IL',
    'IN',
    'IS',
    'IT',
    'JO',
    'JP',
    'KW',
    'LB',
    'LI',
    'LT',
    'LU',
    'LV',
    'MA',
    'MC',
    'MT',
    'MX',
    'MY',
    'NI',
    'NL',
    'NO',
    'NZ',
    'OM',
    'PA',
    'PE',
    'PH',
    'PL',
    'PS',
    'PT',
    'PY',
    'QA',
    'RO',
    'SA',
    'SE',
    'SG',
    'SK',
    'SV',
    'TH',
    'TN',
    'TR',
    'TW',
    'US',
    'UY',
    'VN',
    'ZA'],
   'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/3YLhKiHp1tyCZWM5OnkpPt'},
   'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/3YLhKiHp1tyCZWM5OnkpPt',
   'id': '3YLhKiHp1tyCZWM5OnkpPt',
   'images': [{'height': 640,
     'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b2739af43736b26086fdc17403ba',
     'width': 640},
    {'height': 300,
     'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e029af43736b26086fdc17403ba',
     'width': 300},
    {'height': 64,
     'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d000048519af43736b26086fdc17403ba',
     'width': 64}],
   'name': 'El Sahaba',
   'release_date': '2021-06-16',
   'release_date_precision': 'day',
   'total_tracks': 9,
   'type': 'album',
   'uri': 'spotify:album:3YLhKiHp1tyCZWM5OnkpPt'},
  'artists': [{'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/6CGE1o9Swi1tAEa23wRTah'},
    'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/6CGE1o9Swi1tAEa23wRTah',
    'id': '6CGE1o9Swi1tAEa23wRTah',
    'name': 'Mousv',
    'type': 'artist',
    'uri': 'spotify:artist:6CGE1o9Swi1tAEa23wRTah'}],
  'available_markets': ['AD',
   'AE',
   'AR',
   'AT',
   'AU',
   'BE',
   'BG',
   'BH',
   'BO',
   'BR',
   'CA',
   'CH',
   'CL',
   'CO',
   'CR',
   'CY',
   'CZ',
   'DE',
   'DK',
   'DO',
   'DZ',
   'EC',
   'EE',
   'EG',
   'ES',
   'FI',
   'FR',
   'GB',
   'GR',
   'GT',
   'HK',
   'HN',
   'HU',
   'ID',
   'IE',
   'IL',
   'IN',
   'IS',
   'IT',
   'JO',
   'JP',
   'KW',
   'LB',
   'LI',
   'LT',
   'LU',
   'LV',
   'MA',
   'MC',
   'MT',
   'MX',
   'MY',
   'NI',
   'NL',
   'NO',
   'NZ',
   'OM',
   'PA',
   'PE',
   'PH',
   'PL',
   'PS',
   'PT',
   'PY',
   'QA',
   'RO',
   'SA',
   'SE',
   'SG',
   'SK',
   'SV',
   'TH',
   'TN',
   'TR',
   'TW',
   'US',
   'UY',
   'VN',
   'ZA'],
  'disc_number': 1,
  'duration_ms': 187826,
  'explicit': False,
  'external_ids': {'isrc': 'EGA072100607'},
  'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/track/2imCmZa01FzAv5j0BiD9ab'},
  'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/2imCmZa01FzAv5j0BiD9ab',
  'id': '2imCmZa01FzAv5j0BiD9ab',
  'is_local': False,
  'name': 'SAFINA',
  'popularity': 44,
  'preview_url': 'https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/4feea565830e07e7ac680624092ee625872d47a5?cid=241941eb6adf401aa17987ff97a7d72e',
  'track_number': 2,
  'type': 'track',
  'uri': 'spotify:track:2imCmZa01FzAv5j0BiD9ab'},
 {'album': {'album_type': 'SINGLE',
   'artists': [{'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/7zWFKl03Xg50gKryaEH0gu'},
     'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/7zWFKl03Xg50gKryaEH0gu',
     'id': '7zWFKl03Xg50gKryaEH0gu',
     'name': 'Intomymind',
     'type': 'artist',
     'uri': 'spotify:artist:7zWFKl03Xg50gKryaEH0gu'},
    {'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/0QDlkRZ349RXtT5XcwcLRP'},
     'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/0QDlkRZ349RXtT5XcwcLRP',
     'id': '0QDlkRZ349RXtT5XcwcLRP',
     'name': 'DizzyTooSkinny',
     'type': 'artist',
     'uri': 'spotify:artist:0QDlkRZ349RXtT5XcwcLRP'},
    {'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/0mj273jWZNCOCMIorzMjtw'},
     'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/0mj273jWZNCOCMIorzMjtw',
     'id': '0mj273jWZNCOCMIorzMjtw',
     'name': '2Two',
     'type': 'artist',
     'uri': 'spotify:artist:0mj273jWZNCOCMIorzMjtw'}],
   'available_markets': ['AD',
    'AE',
    'AR',
    'AT',
    'AU',
    'BE',
    'BG',
    'BH',
    'BO',
    'BR',
    'CA',
    'CH',
    'CL',
    'CO',
    'CR',
    'CY',
    'CZ',
    'DE',
    'DK',
    'DO',
    'DZ',
    'EC',
    'EE',
    'EG',
    'ES',
    'FI',
    'FR',
    'GB',
    'GR',
    'GT',
    'HK',
    'HN',
    'HU',
    'ID',
    'IE',
    'IL',
    'IN',
    'IS',
    'IT',
    'JO',
    'JP',
    'KW',
    'LB',
    'LI',
    'LT',
    'LU',
    'LV',
    'MA',
    'MC',
    'MT',
    'MX',
    'MY',
    'NI',
    'NL',
    'NO',
    'NZ',
    'OM',
    'PA',
    'PE',
    'PH',
    'PL',
    'PS',
    'PT',
    'PY',
    'QA',
    'RO',
    'SA',
    'SE',
    'SG',
    'SK',
    'SV',
    'TH',
    'TN',
    'TR',
    'TW',
    'US',
    'UY',
    'VN',
    'ZA'],
   'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/3N08Kioa2qDBucesHQfYcn'},
   'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/3N08Kioa2qDBucesHQfYcn',
   'id': '3N08Kioa2qDBucesHQfYcn',
   'images': [{'height': 640,
     'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b27328ca0085b8f5361784e471bb',
     'width': 640},
    {'height': 300,
     'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e0228ca0085b8f5361784e471bb',
     'width': 300},
    {'height': 64,
     'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000485128ca0085b8f5361784e471bb',
     'width': 64}],
   'name': 'City',
   'release_date': '2021-11-08',
   'release_date_precision': 'day',
   'total_tracks': 1,
   'type': 'album',
   'uri': 'spotify:album:3N08Kioa2qDBucesHQfYcn'},
  'artists': [{'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/7zWFKl03Xg50gKryaEH0gu'},
    'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/7zWFKl03Xg50gKryaEH0gu',
    'id': '7zWFKl03Xg50gKryaEH0gu',
    'name': 'Intomymind',
    'type': 'artist',
    'uri': 'spotify:artist:7zWFKl03Xg50gKryaEH0gu'},
   {'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/0QDlkRZ349RXtT5XcwcLRP'},
    'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/0QDlkRZ349RXtT5XcwcLRP',
    'id': '0QDlkRZ349RXtT5XcwcLRP',
    'name': 'DizzyTooSkinny',
    'type': 'artist',
    'uri': 'spotify:artist:0QDlkRZ349RXtT5XcwcLRP'},
   {'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/0mj273jWZNCOCMIorzMjtw'},
    'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/0mj273jWZNCOCMIorzMjtw',
    'id': '0mj273jWZNCOCMIorzMjtw',
    'name': '2Two',
    'type': 'artist',
    'uri': 'spotify:artist:0mj273jWZNCOCMIorzMjtw'}],
  'available_markets': ['AD',
   'AE',
   'AR',
   'AT',
   'AU',
   'BE',
   'BG',
   'BH',
   'BO',
   'BR',
   'CA',
   'CH',
   'CL',
   'CO',
   'CR',
   'CY',
   'CZ',
   'DE',
   'DK',
   'DO',
   'DZ',
   'EC',
   'EE',
   'EG',
   'ES',
   'FI',
   'FR',
   'GB',
   'GR',
   'GT',
   'HK',
   'HN',
   'HU',
   'ID',
   'IE',
   'IL',
   'IN',
   'IS',
   'IT',
   'JO',
   'JP',
   'KW',
   'LB',
   'LI',
   'LT',
   'LU',
   'LV',
   'MA',
   'MC',
   'MT',
   'MX',
   'MY',
   'NI',
   'NL',
   'NO',
   'NZ',
   'OM',
   'PA',
   'PE',
   'PH',
   'PL',
   'PS',
   'PT',
   'PY',
   'QA',
   'RO',
   'SA',
   'SE',
   'SG',
   'SK',
   'SV',
   'TH',
   'TN',
   'TR',
   'TW',
   'US',
   'UY',
   'VN',
   'ZA'],
  'disc_number': 1,
  'duration_ms': 255039,
  'explicit': True,
  'external_ids': {'isrc': 'QZFYW2142352'},
  'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/track/0tbcK1RvGC7zCeh3z2m8Qb'},
  'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/0tbcK1RvGC7zCeh3z2m8Qb',
  'id': '0tbcK1RvGC7zCeh3z2m8Qb',
  'is_local': False,
  'name': 'City',
  'popularity': 26,
  'preview_url': 'https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/3e687c50e18475e92a747f0c92417b1bf8bbaf06?cid=241941eb6adf401aa17987ff97a7d72e',
  'track_number': 1,
  'type': 'track',
  'uri': 'spotify:track:0tbcK1RvGC7zCeh3z2m8Qb'}]
```

Normalizing the result into a dataframe:

```
NormalizedDf = pd.json_normalize(RespJson2['items'],max_level = 5)
NormalizedDf
```

Result:
[Result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XDLE.png)

The result I'm expecting in the above record is getting only the name of the artists of each track

|  | Artists |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Intomymind,DizzyTooSkinny |
| 1 | ArminVanBuuren,GAIA,ARTY |

I tried playing around with json_normalize() attributes but it put each artist into a record which is not correct, instead, I want a list of track artists per each record.

Code:

```
df_artist = pd.json_normalize(RespJson2['items'], record_path=["artists"], record_prefix="artists")
df_artist
```

Result:
[Result2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNzrq.png)

The artists: (Intomymind,DizzyTooSkinny) should be in one record "artistname" instead of 2 records.

How can I achieve the expected result to be like this?

|  | Artists |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Intomymind,DizzyTooSkinny |
| 1 | ArminVanBuuren,GAIA,ARTY |

Comment: please share the reproducible input

Comment: post your dataframe as dict please, so we can copy it and recreate your issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added the code sample to get the response + the response before being normalized into a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the data you've provided in the question prompt, you can get a frame of just artists by:

1. Accessing `artists` whose value is a `list` of `dicts`
2. The value that you want (the artists' names) belongs to `name` in each dictionary, so you can iterate through `artists` and only return `name`
3. Finally call the `pd.DataFrame` constructor to get your frame of `pd.Series` with col name `Artists`

#### Provided input

```json
{
  "items": [
    {
      "album": {
        "album_type": "SINGLE",
        "artists": [
          {
            "external_urls": {
              "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/7zWFKl03Xg50gKryaEH0gu"
            },
            "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/7zWFKl03Xg50gKryaEH0gu",
            "id": "7zWFKl03Xg50gKryaEH0gu",
            "name": "Intomymind",
            "type": "artist",
            "uri": "spotify:artist:7zWFKl03Xg50gKryaEH0gu"
          },
          {
            "external_urls": {
              "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/0QDlkRZ349RXtT5XcwcLRP"
            },
            "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/0QDlkRZ349RXtT5XcwcLRP",
            "id": "0QDlkRZ349RXtT5XcwcLRP",
            "name": "DizzyTooSkinny",
            "type": "artist",
            "uri": "spotify:artist:0QDlkRZ349RXtT5XcwcLRP"
          }
        ],
        "available_markets": [
          "AD",
          "AE",
          "AR",
          "AT",
          "AU",
          "BE",
          "BG",
          "BH",
          "BO",
          "BR",
          "CA",
          "CH",
          "CL",
          "CO",
          "CR",
          "CY",
          "CZ",
          "DE",
          "DK",
          "DO",
          "DZ",
          "EC",
          "EE",
          "EG",
          "ES",
          "FI",
          "FR",
          "GB",
          "GR",
          "GT",
          "HK",
          "HN",
          "HU",
          "ID",
          "IE",
          "IL",
          "IN",
          "IS",
          "IT",
          "JO",
          "JP",
          "KW",
          "LB",
          "LI",
          "LT",
          "LU",
          "LV",
          "MA",
          "MC",
          "MT",
          "MX",
          "MY",
          "NI",
          "NL",
          "NO",
          "NZ",
          "OM",
          "PA",
          "PE",
          "PH",
          "PL",
          "PS",
          "PT",
          "PY",
          "QA",
          "RO",
          "SA",
          "SE",
          "SG",
          "SK",
          "SV",
          "TH",
          "TN",
          "TR",
          "TW",
          "US",
          "UY",
          "VN",
          "ZA"
        ],
        "external_urls": {
          "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/album/2lmYF8HWF3DYeVR3P6SYf4"
        },
        "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/2lmYF8HWF3DYeVR3P6SYf4",
        "id": "2lmYF8HWF3DYeVR3P6SYf4",
        "images": [
          {
            "height": 640,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b273fbc6dca6a802da6797b0464e",
            "width": 640
          },
          {
            "height": 300,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e02fbc6dca6a802da6797b0464e",
            "width": 300
          },
          {
            "height": 64,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00004851fbc6dca6a802da6797b0464e",
            "width": 64
          }
        ],
        "name": "BrainStorm",
        "release_date": "2021-11-08",
        "release_date_precision": "day",
        "total_tracks": 1,
        "type": "album",
        "uri": "spotify:album:2lmYF8HWF3DYeVR3P6SYf4"
      },
      "artists": [
        {
          "external_urls": {
            "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/7zWFKl03Xg50gKryaEH0gu"
          },
          "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/7zWFKl03Xg50gKryaEH0gu",
          "id": "7zWFKl03Xg50gKryaEH0gu",
          "name": "Intomymind",
          "type": "artist",
          "uri": "spotify:artist:7zWFKl03Xg50gKryaEH0gu"
        },
        {
          "external_urls": {
            "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/0QDlkRZ349RXtT5XcwcLRP"
          },
          "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/0QDlkRZ349RXtT5XcwcLRP",
          "id": "0QDlkRZ349RXtT5XcwcLRP",
          "name": "DizzyTooSkinny",
          "type": "artist",
          "uri": "spotify:artist:0QDlkRZ349RXtT5XcwcLRP"
        }
      ],
      "available_markets": [
        "AD",
        "AE",
        "AR",
        "AT",
        "AU",
        "BE",
        "BG",
        "BH",
        "BO",
        "BR",
        "CA",
        "CH",
        "CL",
        "CO",
        "CR",
        "CY",
        "CZ",
        "DE",
        "DK",
        "DO",
        "DZ",
        "EC",
        "EE",
        "EG",
        "ES",
        "FI",
        "FR",
        "GB",
        "GR",
        "GT",
        "HK",
        "HN",
        "HU",
        "ID",
        "IE",
        "IL",
        "IN",
        "IS",
        "IT",
        "JO",
        "JP",
        "KW",
        "LB",
        "LI",
        "LT",
        "LU",
        "LV",
        "MA",
        "MC",
        "MT",
        "MX",
        "MY",
        "NI",
        "NL",
        "NO",
        "NZ",
        "OM",
        "PA",
        "PE",
        "PH",
        "PL",
        "PS",
        "PT",
        "PY",
        "QA",
        "RO",
        "SA",
        "SE",
        "SG",
        "SK",
        "SV",
        "TH",
        "TN",
        "TR",
        "TW",
        "US",
        "UY",
        "VN",
        "ZA"
      ],
      "disc_number": 1,
      "duration_ms": 150422,
      "explicit": true,
      "external_ids": {
        "isrc": "QZK6K2048245"
      },
      "external_urls": {
        "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/track/6CK4ZX8WhOpkwXf3oO4Uw7"
      },
      "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/6CK4ZX8WhOpkwXf3oO4Uw7",
      "id": "6CK4ZX8WhOpkwXf3oO4Uw7",
      "is_local": false,
      "name": "BrainStorm",
      "popularity": 28,
      "preview_url": "https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/b3a24dfd98cfdd2ef7f083c4b4316ab78c684eab?cid=241941eb6adf401aa17987ff97a7d72e",
      "track_number": 1,
      "type": "track",
      "uri": "spotify:track:6CK4ZX8WhOpkwXf3oO4Uw7"
    },
    {
      "album": {
        "album_type": "ALBUM",
        "artists": [
          {
            "external_urls": {
              "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/6CGE1o9Swi1tAEa23wRTah"
            },
            "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/6CGE1o9Swi1tAEa23wRTah",
            "id": "6CGE1o9Swi1tAEa23wRTah",
            "name": "Mousv",
            "type": "artist",
            "uri": "spotify:artist:6CGE1o9Swi1tAEa23wRTah"
          }
        ],
        "available_markets": [
          "AD",
          "AE",
          "AR",
          "AT",
          "AU",
          "BE",
          "BG",
          "BH",
          "BO",
          "BR",
          "CA",
          "CH",
          "CL",
          "CO",
          "CR",
          "CY",
          "CZ",
          "DE",
          "DK",
          "DO",
          "DZ",
          "EC",
          "EE",
          "EG",
          "ES",
          "FI",
          "FR",
          "GB",
          "GR",
          "GT",
          "HK",
          "HN",
          "HU",
          "ID",
          "IE",
          "IL",
          "IN",
          "IS",
          "IT",
          "JO",
          "JP",
          "KW",
          "LB",
          "LI",
          "LT",
          "LU",
          "LV",
          "MA",
          "MC",
          "MT",
          "MX",
          "MY",
          "NI",
          "NL",
          "NO",
          "NZ",
          "OM",
          "PA",
          "PE",
          "PH",
          "PL",
          "PS",
          "PT",
          "PY",
          "QA",
          "RO",
          "SA",
          "SE",
          "SG",
          "SK",
          "SV",
          "TH",
          "TN",
          "TR",
          "TW",
          "US",
          "UY",
          "VN",
          "ZA"
        ],
        "external_urls": {
          "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/album/3YLhKiHp1tyCZWM5OnkpPt"
        },
        "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/3YLhKiHp1tyCZWM5OnkpPt",
        "id": "3YLhKiHp1tyCZWM5OnkpPt",
        "images": [
          {
            "height": 640,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b2739af43736b26086fdc17403ba",
            "width": 640
          },
          {
            "height": 300,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e029af43736b26086fdc17403ba",
            "width": 300
          },
          {
            "height": 64,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d000048519af43736b26086fdc17403ba",
            "width": 64
          }
        ],
        "name": "El Sahaba",
        "release_date": "2021-06-16",
        "release_date_precision": "day",
        "total_tracks": 9,
        "type": "album",
        "uri": "spotify:album:3YLhKiHp1tyCZWM5OnkpPt"
      },
      "artists": [
        {
          "external_urls": {
            "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/6CGE1o9Swi1tAEa23wRTah"
          },
          "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/6CGE1o9Swi1tAEa23wRTah",
          "id": "6CGE1o9Swi1tAEa23wRTah",
          "name": "Mousv",
          "type": "artist",
          "uri": "spotify:artist:6CGE1o9Swi1tAEa23wRTah"
        }
      ],
      "available_markets": [
        "AD",
        "AE",
        "AR",
        "AT",
        "AU",
        "BE",
        "BG",
        "BH",
        "BO",
        "BR",
        "CA",
        "CH",
        "CL",
        "CO",
        "CR",
        "CY",
        "CZ",
        "DE",
        "DK",
        "DO",
        "DZ",
        "EC",
        "EE",
        "EG",
        "ES",
        "FI",
        "FR",
        "GB",
        "GR",
        "GT",
        "HK",
        "HN",
        "HU",
        "ID",
        "IE",
        "IL",
        "IN",
        "IS",
        "IT",
        "JO",
        "JP",
        "KW",
        "LB",
        "LI",
        "LT",
        "LU",
        "LV",
        "MA",
        "MC",
        "MT",
        "MX",
        "MY",
        "NI",
        "NL",
        "NO",
        "NZ",
        "OM",
        "PA",
        "PE",
        "PH",
        "PL",
        "PS",
        "PT",
        "PY",
        "QA",
        "RO",
        "SA",
        "SE",
        "SG",
        "SK",
        "SV",
        "TH",
        "TN",
        "TR",
        "TW",
        "US",
        "UY",
        "VN",
        "ZA"
      ],
      "disc_number": 1,
      "duration_ms": 187826,
      "explicit": false,
      "external_ids": {
        "isrc": "EGA072100607"
      },
      "external_urls": {
        "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/track/2imCmZa01FzAv5j0BiD9ab"
      },
      "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/2imCmZa01FzAv5j0BiD9ab",
      "id": "2imCmZa01FzAv5j0BiD9ab",
      "is_local": false,
      "name": "SAFINA",
      "popularity": 44,
      "preview_url": "https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/4feea565830e07e7ac680624092ee625872d47a5?cid=241941eb6adf401aa17987ff97a7d72e",
      "track_number": 2,
      "type": "track",
      "uri": "spotify:track:2imCmZa01FzAv5j0BiD9ab"
    },
    {
      "album": {
        "album_type": "SINGLE",
        "artists": [
          {
            "external_urls": {
              "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/7zWFKl03Xg50gKryaEH0gu"
            },
            "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/7zWFKl03Xg50gKryaEH0gu",
            "id": "7zWFKl03Xg50gKryaEH0gu",
            "name": "Intomymind",
            "type": "artist",
            "uri": "spotify:artist:7zWFKl03Xg50gKryaEH0gu"
          },
          {
            "external_urls": {
              "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/0QDlkRZ349RXtT5XcwcLRP"
            },
            "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/0QDlkRZ349RXtT5XcwcLRP",
            "id": "0QDlkRZ349RXtT5XcwcLRP",
            "name": "DizzyTooSkinny",
            "type": "artist",
            "uri": "spotify:artist:0QDlkRZ349RXtT5XcwcLRP"
          },
          {
            "external_urls": {
              "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/0mj273jWZNCOCMIorzMjtw"
            },
            "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/0mj273jWZNCOCMIorzMjtw",
            "id": "0mj273jWZNCOCMIorzMjtw",
            "name": "2Two",
            "type": "artist",
            "uri": "spotify:artist:0mj273jWZNCOCMIorzMjtw"
          }
        ],
        "available_markets": [
          "AD",
          "AE",
          "AR",
          "AT",
          "AU",
          "BE",
          "BG",
          "BH",
          "BO",
          "BR",
          "CA",
          "CH",
          "CL",
          "CO",
          "CR",
          "CY",
          "CZ",
          "DE",
          "DK",
          "DO",
          "DZ",
          "EC",
          "EE",
          "EG",
          "ES",
          "FI",
          "FR",
          "GB",
          "GR",
          "GT",
          "HK",
          "HN",
          "HU",
          "ID",
          "IE",
          "IL",
          "IN",
          "IS",
          "IT",
          "JO",
          "JP",
          "KW",
          "LB",
          "LI",
          "LT",
          "LU",
          "LV",
          "MA",
          "MC",
          "MT",
          "MX",
          "MY",
          "NI",
          "NL",
          "NO",
          "NZ",
          "OM",
          "PA",
          "PE",
          "PH",
          "PL",
          "PS",
          "PT",
          "PY",
          "QA",
          "RO",
          "SA",
          "SE",
          "SG",
          "SK",
          "SV",
          "TH",
          "TN",
          "TR",
          "TW",
          "US",
          "UY",
          "VN",
          "ZA"
        ],
        "external_urls": {
          "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/album/3N08Kioa2qDBucesHQfYcn"
        },
        "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/3N08Kioa2qDBucesHQfYcn",
        "id": "3N08Kioa2qDBucesHQfYcn",
        "images": [
          {
            "height": 640,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b27328ca0085b8f5361784e471bb",
            "width": 640
          },
          {
            "height": 300,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e0228ca0085b8f5361784e471bb",
            "width": 300
          },
          {
            "height": 64,
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000485128ca0085b8f5361784e471bb",
            "width": 64
          }
        ],
        "name": "City",
        "release_date": "2021-11-08",
        "release_date_precision": "day",
        "total_tracks": 1,
        "type": "album",
        "uri": "spotify:album:3N08Kioa2qDBucesHQfYcn"
      },
      "artists": [
        {
          "external_urls": {
            "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/7zWFKl03Xg50gKryaEH0gu"
          },
          "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/7zWFKl03Xg50gKryaEH0gu",
          "id": "7zWFKl03Xg50gKryaEH0gu",
          "name": "Intomymind",
          "type": "artist",
          "uri": "spotify:artist:7zWFKl03Xg50gKryaEH0gu"
        },
        {
          "external_urls": {
            "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/0QDlkRZ349RXtT5XcwcLRP"
          },
          "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/0QDlkRZ349RXtT5XcwcLRP",
          "id": "0QDlkRZ349RXtT5XcwcLRP",
          "name": "DizzyTooSkinny",
          "type": "artist",
          "uri": "spotify:artist:0QDlkRZ349RXtT5XcwcLRP"
        },
        {
          "external_urls": {
            "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/0mj273jWZNCOCMIorzMjtw"
          },
          "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/0mj273jWZNCOCMIorzMjtw",
          "id": "0mj273jWZNCOCMIorzMjtw",
          "name": "2Two",
          "type": "artist",
          "uri": "spotify:artist:0mj273jWZNCOCMIorzMjtw"
        }
      ],
      "available_markets": [
        "AD",
        "AE",
        "AR",
        "AT",
        "AU",
        "BE",
        "BG",
        "BH",
        "BO",
        "BR",
        "CA",
        "CH",
        "CL",
        "CO",
        "CR",
        "CY",
        "CZ",
        "DE",
        "DK",
        "DO",
        "DZ",
        "EC",
        "EE",
        "EG",
        "ES",
        "FI",
        "FR",
        "GB",
        "GR",
        "GT",
        "HK",
        "HN",
        "HU",
        "ID",
        "IE",
        "IL",
        "IN",
        "IS",
        "IT",
        "JO",
        "JP",
        "KW",
        "LB",
        "LI",
        "LT",
        "LU",
        "LV",
        "MA",
        "MC",
        "MT",
        "MX",
        "MY",
        "NI",
        "NL",
        "NO",
        "NZ",
        "OM",
        "PA",
        "PE",
        "PH",
        "PL",
        "PS",
        "PT",
        "PY",
        "QA",
        "RO",
        "SA",
        "SE",
        "SG",
        "SK",
        "SV",
        "TH",
        "TN",
        "TR",
        "TW",
        "US",
        "UY",
        "VN",
        "ZA"
      ],
      "disc_number": 1,
      "duration_ms": 255039,
      "explicit": true,
      "external_ids": {
        "isrc": "QZFYW2142352"
      },
      "external_urls": {
        "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/track/0tbcK1RvGC7zCeh3z2m8Qb"
      },
      "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/0tbcK1RvGC7zCeh3z2m8Qb",
      "id": "0tbcK1RvGC7zCeh3z2m8Qb",
      "is_local": false,
      "name": "City",
      "popularity": 26,
      "preview_url": "https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/3e687c50e18475e92a747f0c92417b1bf8bbaf06?cid=241941eb6adf401aa17987ff97a7d72e",
      "track_number": 1,
      "type": "track",
      "uri": "spotify:track:0tbcK1RvGC7zCeh3z2m8Qb"
    }
  ]
}
```

#### Get artist name per record

```py
artists: list = RespJson2["items"][0]["artists"]
df_artist = pd.DataFrame(data={"Artists": [", ".join([artists[ix]["name"] for ix, _ in enumerate(artists)])]})
```

#### Output

|  | Artists |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Intomymind, DizzyTooSkinny |

*The artists in the second row of your expected output are *not* in the provided data, but the steps for getting them are similar to how we got the artists in the first row here.